# Comparing dates stored in date objects and getting a boolean returned

Tags: java

I am having trouble comparing dates in Java I have tried:

```
(today == actDate)

(today.equals(actDate))
```

Both always seem to evaluate to false:

[image]

In the image above the first date is today and the second is actDate.

Both are date objects:

```
Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

Date actDate = new Date(taskHours.get(j).getDate().getTime());
```

Then I tried using compareTo, but this appears to return a 1 if the date is greater and a -1 if lower.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The dates seem different...

Comment: The first one has both 2013-05-03

Comment: Are they equal at the millisencond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` differ. This might be the reason.

Comment: THis appears to be the reason. Thanks. Would comparing the strings work?

Comment: @DavidTunnell Give it a try.

Comment: (!today.toString().equals(actDate.toString())) works, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

your problem is `Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());`. With this you use the current system-time in milliseconds , which are stored in the date object. Your second date doesn't hold the information with milliseconds and this why every comparison fails.

Comment: You should use Calendar to clear specific unwanted components of your date, typically to round backwards (usually to the previous midnight or to the previous whole second or minute) or to set the same day, month and year to compare only the hour of the day.

Answer (score 2):

Working with dates is a bit tricky. You need to use `compareTo` as JDBC works with `java.sql.Timestamp` and within application you usually work with `java.util.Date`. Two objects are (usually) not considered to be equal if they are instances of two different classes (even thou they might be from the same hierarchy).

What you want to do is:

```
public boolean isSameDate(Date date1, Date date2) {
    return date1.compareTo(date2) == 0;
}
```

If you want to make your life easier when `null` values come in play, use *commons-lang*:

```
public boolean isSameDate(Date date1, Date date2) {
    return ObjectUtils.compare(date1, date2) == 0;
}
```

---

If you want to compare just the date information (not the time), then I suggest you to use *Joda Time* library (namely `LocalDate` class). Converting timestamps to calendar date objects is not a straghtforward (one line of code) task with standard Java components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Date#after(Date when)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) and [Date#before(Date otherDate)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) methods to compare dates and achive some order.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing 2 different dates (maybe seconds are different), so `equals` method return false which is expected. Using `equals` is the right way to compere them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object instead. And manually compare day, month and year separately.

```
Calendar cal1 = new Calendar();
cal1.setTime(date1);
Calendar cal2 = new Calendar();
cal2.setTime(date2);

boolean equal = true;
equal &= cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
equal &= cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
equal &= cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```